# SEO / Same product for sale on on own e-commerce and marketplace: alternate links for marketplace listings?

Tags: seo, rel-canonical, rel-alternate

Assume that **a product is for sale on both own e-commerce and marketplace(s)**, with the same picture, quite a similar title, and description.

Although they might be some differences like a more detailed product description in own shop, to a certain extent, both offers are quite similar: the underlying product is the same and the product picture is itself a duplicate.

Selling on one's own e-shop is more advantageous than on a marketplace, but the latter gives more visibility to the product as people also search within the marketplace.

Then,  ‒ from an SEO perspective ‒ how to give the product on its own e-shop a ranking boost as compared to its "equivalent" listing on the marketplace?

**Would it be relevant to mention marketplace listings as alternate links?**

```
<head>
(...)
<link rel="canonical" href="https://own-shop.com/product-1234" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example-marketplace-1/45678" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example-marketplace-2/6789012" />
(...)
</head>
```

Would this have a **positive impact?**
« Hey search engines, before displaying my marketplace listing, don't forget to send customers here first! Please display my own shop listing above its marketplace siblings. »

... with possibly an unwanted side effect of deindexing the marketplace listing, for the benefit of competitors?

Or a **negative impact**, like outbound links, that would reinforce the ranking of the marketplace listing, to the detriment of the own e-shop?

Or **no impact** at all?

Has anyone performed an A/B test of this idea?

I can't find any documentation on this topic.

Comment: Is this marketplace a third party that you have no direct control over?  If you have any control there, it would make more sense to put meta tags on the marketplace page pointing to your main site.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be relevant to mention marketplaces listings as alternate
> links?

It depends on the purpose of your many links for one product. If the goal is only to increase sales, then this can work. Google will choose one url as canonical and show it in the SERP. **[What is canonicalization](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/canonicalization)** of Google:

> Canonicalization is the process of selecting the representative
> –canonical– URL of a piece of content. Consequently, a canonical URL
> is the URL of a page that Google chose as the most representative from
> a set of duplicate pages. Often called deduplication, this process
> helps Google show only one version of the otherwise duplicate content
> in its search results.

If the goal is to promote your e-commerce, then it makes sense to list the e-commerce content as canonical. Check the **[google quote](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls?hl=en#reasons-to-specify-a-canonical-url)**:

> While it's generally not critical to specify a canonical preference
> for your URLs, there are a number of reasons why you would want to
> explicitly tell Google about a canonical page in a set of duplicate or
> similar pages:
>
> **To specify which URL that you want people to see in search results.**

The `rel="alternate"` you specified in the example makes sense when using `hreflang`. Read more **[Tell Google about localized versions of your page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions)**.